# How to keep track of pairs of points

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to keep track of pairs of points when they are represented. For a set of pair of points like:

```
newx = {{{0.135104, 0.424232}, {0.0700024, 0.464537}}, {{0.968525, 
   0.346787}, {0.822588, 0.884112}}, {{0.908807, 0.389676}, {0.698018,
    0.815693}}, {{0.465015, 0.805677}, {0.268573, 
   0.857867}}, {{0.747337, 0.788575}, {0.497344, 
   0.893726}}, {{0.355489, 0.987499}, {0.197186, 
   0.989964}}, {{0.183918, 0.282062}, {0.0966277, 
   0.351434}}, {{0.749388, 0.361435}, {0.499389, 0.680327}},[![enter image description here][1]][1]   {{0.277621, 
   0.191408}, {0.150071, 0.312754}}, {{0.513538, 0.867554}, {0.302532,
    0.907623}}}
```

I plot them (with a diagonal line, not important):

```
ListPlot[newx, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
```

[image]

In case of having small number of pairs, I can identify them visually, but having a large number of them is problematic.

Any idea about how to identify pairs of points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility would be to connect like-colored dots with lines:

```
Show[ListPlot[newx, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], Graphics[Line /@ newx]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `ListLinePlot` with the option `PlotMarkers`:

```
ListLinePlot[newx, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Dotted, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[MatrixForm /@ newx, Right], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> True,
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[Length@newx - 1]; 

Graphics[MapThread[{Opacity[.2, #],  
    CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[15], Line@#2, Opacity[1], #, 
    AbsolutePointSize[7], Point @ #2} &, {colors, newx}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

You can also put pairs in separate blobs (similar to community regions in [`CommunityGraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CommunityGraphPlot.html)):

```
ClearAll[blobS]
blobS = Module[{}, CommunityGraphPlot[{}]; 
  GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`generateBlobs[Automatic, {#}, .01][[2, 1]]]&;
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
colors = RandomColor[Length@newx];

Graphics[MapThread[{Darker @ #, PointSize[Large], Point @ #2, 
    Opacity[.5, Lighter @ #], EdgeForm[Gray], blobS @ #2} &, 
    {colors, newx}], 
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
newx = {
   {{0.135104, 0.424232}, {0.0700024, 0.464537}},
   {{0.968525, 0.346787}, {0.822588, 0.884112}},
   {{0.908807, 0.389676}, {0.698018, 0.815693}},
   {{0.465015, 0.805677}, {0.268573, 0.857867}},
   {{0.747337, 0.788575}, {0.497344, 0.893726}},
   {{0.355489, 0.987499}, {0.197186, 0.989964}},
   {{0.183918, 0.282062}, {0.0966277, 0.351434}},
   {{0.749388, 0.361435}, {0.499389, 0.680327}}, 
   {{0.277621, 0.191408}, {0.150071, 0.312754}},
   {{0.513538, 0.867554}, {0.302532, 0.907623}}};

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[newx,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  PlotStyle -> ReplacePart[
    ConstantArray[Automatic, Length[newx]],
    pair -> AbsolutePointSize[10]]],
 {{pair, 1, "Pair"}, Range[Length[newx]],
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]